# How to specify image format to use when knitting .Rmd to .md using knitr

Tags: r, knitr

In my `.Rmd` file I specify

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(dev=c('pdf', 'png'))
```

which produces figures in both PDF and PNG formats (I need both). However, the knitted `.md` includes references to the PDF images. If I change the order of formats in my chunk options, the first format in the list will be used. I am assuming `knitr` looks for an image with a given base name and includes the first matching file that shows up, regardless of extension.

How can I tell `knitr` to use PNG instead, even though PDFs were generated first? More generally, how can I specify the default image extension to include in `.md`, regardless of what additional formats were generated and in what order?

Comment: Why does it matter the order the different versions of a figure are generated? If you want to use PNG, why can't you just put `'png'` first?

Comment: I generate many images in each of my reports and often use cache to retrieve them and subsequently add them to the `.md`. I do not want to have to rerun the report using a different order and regenerate figures, but rather specify which format to use; especially if I want to generate two reports - one with PNGs and the other with PDFs.

Comment: In that case editing the `.md` file directly might be easiest.

Comment: [this old post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/knitr/Denmuf7K1Og/aERn_iPNPhUJ) might help; it would be nice to update the solution to work with rmarkdown.

Comment: thanks @baptiste, I'll look into stripping the extension.